# Acquiring different tree barks in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'd like to collect different bark types from trees to build a house but I'm having a hard time growing trees with birch and dark barks.

If I plant a sapling then what is the probability of getting a tree with birch or dark bark? Is there anywhere I can plant a sapling to increase my chances?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the [minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sapling):

> "Saplings will only grow into generic trees, never into birch or pine trees, even if the saplings came from the foliage of those trees."

As of version 1.5:

> Since Beta 1.5, birch, spruce/pine, and oak trees drop birch, spruce/pine, and oak saplings, respectively, although birch and spruce/pine trees will still drop oak saplings as well. Pre-Beta 1.5, trees only ever dropped oak saplings, regardless of tree type.

Comment: Unfortunately this is true, I hope different trees drop different sapling types eventually.

Comment: So birch and pine are non-renewable? D:

Comment: Yup, unless an update changing this is released.

Comment: Notch mentioned in a [live stream with Coe](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T6bks8lpDK4) that it's a bug and that it would be fixed eventually. I can't find the exact time it's mentioned, but it's somewhere in that video.

Comment: didn't know michael madsen played minecraft :D

Answer (score 6):

Pine and birch saplings have recently been added to the game! You can plant them and they will create a tree of the kind of sapling they are.

Comment: This is correct; I recently harvested a fair number of birch saplings to help start a birch farm -- the sapling's inventory icon looks different, with a color similar to the birch bark in place of the brown in a regular sapling's inventory icon.  Break a birch tree's leaves to get birch saplings (though note that in forests, a regular tree's leaves may be adjacent to a birch's leaves if the trees are close enough, and you'd of course get regular saplings from the regular tree's leaves).  I assume the same holds true for pine, which I haven't bothered harvesting yet.

Comment: @Doktor I've harvested some pines—the sapling icon is quite different, and produces pines as expected.

Answer (score 5):

According to [a tweet by Jens](https://twitter.com/jeb_/status/55976702232379392), spruce and birch saplings will soon be added to the game.

> Heads-up to texture packers: Slot (15, 3) is now spruce sapling and slot (15, 4) is birch sapling (counting coords from 0)

Presumably, each type of tree will soon drop its own type of sapling, so you'll be able to grow more.

Comment: If this is going to be added to Beta 1.5, Notch says it should be next week! (week beginning 11/4)

Comment: Awesome, be sure to update your answer once it happens. I'll update my question as well because probabilities will be out of the question (birch 100% of the time gives birch, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a mod to enable different tree barks, if you wish. I believe there was one. Otherwise, you can also edit the source code.

Comment: inventory editing programs can probably do it easily as well.

Comment: What source code?

Comment: Java is easy to decompile back into the code which created it.

Comment: why decompile when you have APIs?

Comment: I don't think there's much point to this any more, with the advent of separate saplings :)